# How to get a new array without empty properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For ex I have an array:

```
array = [
    {age: 5,
     name: 'John'},
    {age: 6,
     name: 'Ronald'},
    {age: 3,
     name: ''}
]
```

What I should do to get new array without empty property such as the 3d object ? 
Like a

```
newArray = [
    {age: 5,
     name: 'John'},
    {age: 6,
     name: 'Ronald'},
]
```

Need to use only vanila JS without jquery and so on.. thank you guys!

Comment: array.filter(function(a){ return a.name; }) would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` with object destructuring to keep the code simple:

```js
var array = [
    {age: 5,
     name: 'John'},
    {age: 6,
     name: 'Ronald'},
    {age: 3,
     name: ''}
];
var res = array.filter(({name}) => name);
console.log(res);
```

If you want to check both the properties then use `name && age` in `filter` condition:

```js
var array = [
    {age: 5,
     name: 'John'},
    {age: 6,
     name: 'Ronald'},
    {age: 3,
     name: ''},
    {age: '',
     name: ''}
];
var res = array.filter(({name, age}) => name && age);
console.log(res);
```

If you also expect to run the code perfectly on IE browser then use simple check without ES6:

```js
var array = [
    {age: 5,
     name: 'John'},
    {age: 6,
     name: 'Ronald'},
    {age: 3,
     name: ''},
    {age: '',
     name: ''}
];
var res = [];
array.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.age && item.name){
    res.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const newArray = array.filter(item => item.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This filter by empty name

```
array.filter((obj) => obj.name)
```

Comment: There is no need to check if string is empty for the second time.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: `obj.name` test returns false for empty string.